# Having issues renaming file extensions of multiple files at once through terminal. "Rename" comm, does not seem to work

Tags: batch-rename

I have a lot of video files that are in mixed formats (.avi, .mkv, .wmv) that I need to change to ".mp4". All of the video files are within one main directory, but also flow into sub directories under that as well. I have looked up how to bulk rename file extension, but I just can't seem to get it. I am using Ubuntu LTS 10.04. I hope that someone can assist.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use find ;)

```
for i in .{avi,mkv,wmv}; do find . *$i -exec /bin/rename $i .mp4 '{}' \; ; done
```